# Failing to get provider data from React.Context API

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn the context api for react but I think I'm confused about some of the principles of it. The tuts that I follow don't ever work. I'm on the correct version of React.

Context.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: 'Kelly'
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <MyContext.Provider context={{
        value: this.state.value
      }}>{this.props.children}</MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MyProvider from '../Context';

const App = () => {
  return(
    <MyProvider>
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
          <p>{context}</p>
        )}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
      </MyProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works, the way you are passing context value is not correct. Please check the following link
[context example](https://codepen.io/stack26/pen/yEePav)

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userName: 'Kelly'
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.userName}>                           
           {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <MyProvider>
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
          <p>{context}</p>
        )}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    </MyProvider>
  );  
  }

}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: It gives the same error as before "Uncaught ReferenceError: MyContext is not defined". I'm importing MyProvider to the component that needs it but it isn't working :/.

Comment: Some other issues must be there. As you can see in the link mentioned by me. It works fine. check for other issue in imports. May be there where you are doing it wrong

Comment: I think I had a typo because when I copy/pasted your code in place of mine it worked even though I don't think anything changed